# Create a local db in winform and get data from server in the background

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, caching

I'm looking for a way to enhance the performance of my application which excessively uses the database that is hosted on a server, The application needs to remotely access the database thus, causing it to be slow, so I was thinking about creating a local database and populating it from the server the minute the application is  run, and afterwards performing updates on a regular basis to the hosted mySQl database after every hour or when the user decides to logout, the main issue I have is I will be having 10-20 users, they don't update the same kind of data but how will I know which tables have been updated and according to that I would apply the changes over my hosted database? and is there any article or link that has further explanation regarding this issue?

My Application is a C# windows form application and the database is mysql database.

One of the queries that I have and takes too long to execute is this one:

```
 /**
  * getting the schedule based on the submitted id
  * */
    public static Schedule2 getTeachersSchedule(String therapistID, int weekday, int period, int school_year)
    {
        // connecting to mysql database
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM student_schedule2, weekday, school_year, period, task where school_year_id = school_year_id_fk AND therapist_id_fk =" + therapistID + " AND weekday_id = weekday_id_fk AND period_id=period_id_fk AND task_id=task_id_fk AND weekday_id=" + weekday + " AND period_id=" + period + " AND school_year_id =" + school_year, myConn))
                {
                    MySqlDataReader reader;
                    myConn.Open();
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    Schedule2 schedule = null;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        schedule = new Schedule2();
                        schedule.ID = reader.GetInt32("student_schedule2_id");
                        try
                        {
                            if (reader["student_id_fk"] != DBNull.Value)
                                schedule.student = getStudent(reader.GetString("student_id_fk"));
                            else
                                schedule.student = null;
                            Weekday weekDay = new Weekday();
                            weekDay.ID = reader.GetInt32("weekday_id");
                            weekDay.weekdayName = reader.GetString("weekday_name");
                            schedule.weekday = weekDay;
                            schedule.semesterName = reader.GetString("semester_name");
                            Period periodObj = new Period();
                            SchoolYear schoolYEar = new SchoolYear();
                            periodObj.ID = reader.GetInt32("period_id");
                            periodObj.period_name = reader.GetString("period_name");
                            schedule.period = periodObj;
                            schoolYEar.ID = reader.GetInt32("school_year_id");
                            schoolYEar.year_name = reader.GetString("school_year_name");
                            schedule.schoolYear = schoolYEar;
                            Task course = new Task();
                            course.ID = reader.GetInt32("task_id");
                            course.taskName = reader.GetString("task_name");
                            schedule.task = course;
                            schedule.therapist = getTherapist(reader.GetString("therapist_id_fk"));
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }

                    }

                    myConn.Close();
                    return schedule;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gets extremely complicated very quickly. As a start, any system settings or other data which *you know won't be changed* can be read into fields within a static class without too many problems. The rest is too complicated to cover in generic terms - for the small number of users you're talking about I suspect it wouldn't be worth trying to add synchronization.

Comment: @Octopoid so you suggest that I shouldn't consider doing it? the problem is the internet is slow sometimes thus, causing my application to be slow

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that, but synchronizing a database really is extremely complicated. The simplest way to do it would be to download everything, then sync and deal with any data conflicts when you quit, but then it'll make your application VERY slow to load, plus providing an interface to deal with the conflicts is a lot of work. The better way would be to only cache the data they're actually viewing, but that only helps with repeated viewings of a record, and gets excruciatingly complicated. Honestly, your best bet is to just improve the performance of your database as much as you can.

Comment: It might be best if you update your question with an example SQL statement which is currently particularly slow to execute, so we can see what the problem might be. Are you using complicated joins? How much data are you pulling? Are you executing lots of statements where 1 would do? However, if the problem really is just very slow internet, there might be little you can do to help them, without trying to implement something that large companies have tried and failed to do (very well) any number of times!..

Comment: I have forexample a schedule table which includes data for 8 periods a day and 5 days a week for each user, when I try to get the data, I usually query the database one at a time for each day and period so I have 8 queries for sunday, 8 queries for monday and so on, this page takes so much time to load,  I will edit the question and add the code of this query

Comment: It would be better to try and change that to a single query that pulls all of the data you want, as this will reduce the network bandwidth required considerably. But yeah, add the code and we can suggest how to improve it.

Comment: and I'm using crystal reports, these too take a lot of time to load, especially when I need to print a report which collects data from all the departments, the query for crystal reports itself is the default one I got when I used to instructions to choose the tables I needed for the report and the linking they had, I didn't type this query it was generated automatically

Comment: Sort the normal app data access first, apply the theories across your app after. If your reports are still slow, post another question.

Comment: @Octopoid I have edited the question and added the query, could the problem be because I'm using where period_id=period_id_fk etc instead of using the joins in my queries?

Comment: If you're calling that method multiple times in a row, that's likely to be slow - you probably need to look into creating a SQL stored procedure that does all of that work in the database and returns everything you need in one go.

Comment: yes @Octopoid it's being called 8 times for each day thus 40 times in a row! As you can see my work is all object oriented by using the stored procedures I would still be able to maintain the output and save it in objects similar to the way I'm doing it right now?

Comment: what about the where clause for the foreign keys? should I use joins instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will be prone to stale data and most likely be slower, since all data will be sent over the network.

I suggest you look at your SQL queries and determine why they are slow.  Adding indexes to the table will help enormously.

Comment: I already have indexes in my tables, should I increase them to make them execute faster? can you give me an example of what indexes I should add?